# How to Create Cypress Tree With Customize Shape

Tags: modeling, objects, particles

I want to make a Cypress tree model. I tried it self-taught at Blender yesterday. And I don't really understand much about particle systems.
Here it looks like my model is almost similar to the original Cypress. I use the low poly method for the leaves. By using images as planes addon. But the shape is less pointed and the leaves also look unkempt making it less similar. What should I do so I can shape the leaves as freely as possible? and similar as in the photo. Are there other methods that are just as simple as this?

Here is some photo and image to explain it better.
[image]

And here my particle system settings

[image]

Sorry for my bad english and explanation. Not my first language.

Comment: You should try the built-in sapling addon. It can make many tree shapes with great control.